# angular random css rotation always moving

Tags: css, angularjs, rotation, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I would like to have an img with a random css rotation. I managed to achieve this, but when you move your mouse over the leaftlet map, the img is always spinning around:

http://jsfiddle.net/J03rgPf/mzwwfav4/3/

How can I set a random css only once, so that the getRandRot function is not called again and again?

```
<body ng-controller="DemoController">
 <leaflet center="center"></leaflet>
 <div class="{{getRandRot()}}">
     <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0a/Surfers_at_Mavericks.jpg/320px-Surfers_at_Mavericks.jpg" />
 </div>  
</body>
```

Angular JS Code:

```
var app = angular.module('demoapp',['leaflet-directive']);

app.controller('DemoController', [ '$scope', 'leafletData', function($scope, leafletData) {
    angular.extend($scope, {
        center: {
            lat: 51.505,
            lng: -0.09,
            zoom: 5
        }
    })

    $scope.getRandRot = function(){
        var rotations = [ "rotate-10", "rotate-5", "rotate5", "rotate10" ];
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * rotations.length);
        return rotations[rand];  
      }
}]);
```

CSS

```
.angular-leaflet-map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 280px;
}

.rotate-10{
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
.rotate-5{
    -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
}
.rotate5{
    -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
}
.rotate10{
    -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(10deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe assign response of call to getRandRot to a value in your controller ?

By using `class={{ getRandRot() }}`, you're creating a bind onto `getRandRot` which will be called within each digest phase

This does the trick:

HTML

```
 <body ng-controller="DemoController">
   <leaflet center="center"></leaflet>
   <div ng-class="randRot">
     <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0a/Surfers_at_Mavericks.jpg/320px-Surfers_at_Mavericks.jpg" />
   </div>  
</body>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('demoapp',['leaflet-directive']);

app.controller('DemoController', [ '$scope', 'leafletData', function($scope, leafletData) {
    angular.extend($scope, {
        center: {
            lat: 51.505,
            lng: -0.09,
            zoom: 5
        }
    })

    getRandRot = function(){
        var rotations = [ "rotate-10", "rotate-5", "rotate5", "rotate10" ];
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * rotations.length);
        return rotations[rand];  
      }

    $scope.randRot = getRandRot();
}]);
```

And by the way, ng-class is the preferred way to dynamically set class on element with angular.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works almost. When I look in the site sourcecode, ng-class is set to ng-class="rotate10". But the rotation doesnt happen. Also not when I write directly ng-class="rotate10". But when I write class="rotate10" the rotation works... Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly your problem. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3xr4kwu/1/) contains what I thought the solution to your problem was. What is different from what you expected?